# react-redux <Provider> missing dynamically added reducer state

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am dynamically adding removing reducers to redux state and using react-redux connect function to map state to props. I do adding/removing reducers as shown in
https://redux.js.org/recipes/code-splitting using reducerManager method.

at some point below code runs

```
...
store.reducerManager.add(campaign.campaignId, UDP.getReducer()); 
console.log('reducer map', store.reducerManager.getReducerMap()); 
return (<UDP campaign={campaign}/>);
....
```

which subsequently mounts UDP:

```
...
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
console.log('[stt]', state)
return({ 
    language:         state.appstate.language,
    currentViewData:  state.appstate.currentViewData,
    currentView:      state.appstate.currentView,
    connectedStampId: state.bluetooth.connectedStampId,
    isBTConnected:  state.bluetooth.isBTConnected,
    isActing:       state[ownProps.campaign.campaignId].isActing, 
})
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,null,null) (UDP);
```

The issue is that when mapStateToProps runs,

```
state[ownProps.campaign.campaignId]
```

is undefined whereas console.log('reducer map'... shows that it's in the state. However the state that passed into mapStateToProps does not contain it.

(also mapStateToProps runs a second time right after first then the state is correct)

I don't know if i am doing something not allowed (by Provider/react-redux) or doing something wrong.